# A status bar for the VBE

Tags: c#, rubberduck, com

One of the most annoying things about the VBE (VBA's IDE), is that it doesn't have a status bar.

Rubberduck 2.0 works around this by introducing the `RubberduckCommandBar`, which [ab]uses `msoControlButton` controls as though they were labels - the command bar constantly resizes as the text changes, but at least we get to show context-sensitive information about the current selection:

[image: Rubberduck 2.0 commandbar showing information about the current selection: "VBAProject (Refresh).ParameterPromptForm (L9C21-L9C26): Model (property set accessor)"]

Because Rubberduck loads all referenced COM types and resolves references regardless of whether or not an identifier is built-in, the "status bar" also displays type information when the selection is on an identifier reference for a built-in declaration, e.g. an `Excel.ListObject`:

[image: works for built-in declarations too: "Excel.ListObject: QueryTable (property get accessor) L74C20"]

...or even built-in functions from the VBA standard library:

[image: "Format$" resolves to "VBA.Strings._B_str_Format" (function)]

---

If that's a wonderful feature, the code for it is a little less "wonderful". Here's the entire `RubberduckCommandBar` class, I'm particularly unimpressed with the `SetSelectionText` implementation - how can it be written better?

```
public class RubberduckCommandBar
{
    private readonly RubberduckParserState _state;
    private readonly VBE _vbe;
    private readonly IShowParserErrorsCommand _command;

    private CommandBarButton _refreshButton;
    private CommandBarButton _statusButton;
    private CommandBarButton _selectionButton;

    public RubberduckCommandBar(RubberduckParserState state, VBE vbe, IShowParserErrorsCommand command)
    {
        _state = state;
        _vbe = vbe;
        _command = command;
        _state.StateChanged += State_StateChanged;
        Initialize();
    }

    private void _statusButton_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        if (_state.Status == ParserState.Error)
        {
            _command.Execute(null);
        }
    }

    public void SetStatusText(string value = null)
    {
        UiDispatcher.Invoke(() => _statusButton.Caption = value ?? RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("ParserState_" + _state.Status));
    }

    public void SetSelectionText(Declaration declaration)
    {
        if (declaration == null && _vbe.ActiveCodePane != null)
        {
            var selection = _vbe.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection();
            SetSelectionText(selection);
        }
        else if (declaration != null && !declaration.IsBuiltIn && declaration.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Class && declaration.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Module)
        {
            _selectionButton.Caption = string.Format("{0} ({1}): {2} ({3})", 
                declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName,
                declaration.QualifiedSelection.Selection,
                declaration.IdentifierName,
                RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("DeclarationType_" + declaration.DeclarationType));
        }
        else if (declaration != null)
        {
            var selection = _vbe.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection();
            _selectionButton.Caption = string.Format("{0}: {1} ({2}) {3}",
                declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName,
                declaration.IdentifierName,
                RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("DeclarationType_" + declaration.DeclarationType),
                selection.Selection);
        }
    }

    private void SetSelectionText(QualifiedSelection selection)
    {
        UiDispatcher.Invoke(() => _selectionButton.Caption = selection.ToString());
    }

    private void State_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RubberduckCommandBar handles StateChanged...");
        SetStatusText(RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("ParserState_" + _state.Status));
    }

    public event EventHandler Refresh;

    private void OnRefresh()
    {
        var handler = Refresh;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        var commandbar = _vbe.CommandBars.Add("Rubberduck", MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop, false, true);

        _refreshButton = (CommandBarButton)commandbar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
        ParentMenuItemBase.SetButtonImage(_refreshButton, Resources.arrow_circle_double, Resources.arrow_circle_double_mask);
        _refreshButton.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIcon;
        _refreshButton.Tag = "Refresh";
        _refreshButton.TooltipText =RubberduckUI.RubberduckCommandbarRefreshButtonTooltip;
        _refreshButton.Click += refreshButton_Click;

        _statusButton = (CommandBarButton)commandbar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
        _statusButton.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
        _statusButton.Tag = "Status";
        _statusButton.Click += _statusButton_Click;

        _selectionButton = (CommandBarButton)commandbar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
        _selectionButton.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
        _selectionButton.BeginGroup = true;
        _selectionButton.Enabled = false;

        commandbar.Visible = true;
    }

    private void refreshButton_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        OnRefresh();
    }
}
```

Is anything else out of place?

That code is called from the `App` class, in mouse and keyboard hook event handlers:

```
private void HandleMouseMessage()
{
    RefreshSelection();
}

private void HandleKeyboardMessage()
{
    RefreshSelection();
}

private void RefreshSelection()
{
    _stateBar.SetSelectionText(_parser.State.FindSelectedDeclaration(_vbe.ActiveCodePane));
    _appMenus.EvaluateCanExecute(_parser.State);
}
```

Here's the `FindSelectedDeclaration` implementation, found in the `RubberduckParserState` class:

```
private QualifiedSelection _lastSelection;
private Declaration _selectedDeclaration;

public Declaration FindSelectedDeclaration(CodePane activeCodePane)
{
    var selection = activeCodePane.GetSelection();
    if (selection.Equals(_lastSelection))
    {
        return _selectedDeclaration;
    }

    _lastSelection = selection;
    _selectedDeclaration = null;

    if (!selection.Equals(default(QualifiedSelection)))
    {
        var matches = AllDeclarations
            .Where(item => item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Project &&
                           item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.ModuleOption &&
                           item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Class &&
                           item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Module &&
                           (IsSelectedDeclaration(selection, item) ||
                            item.References.Any(reference => IsSelectedReference(selection, reference))));
        try
        {
            var match = matches.SingleOrDefault() ?? AllUserDeclarations
                .SingleOrDefault(item => (item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Class || item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Module)
                        && item.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Equals(selection.QualifiedName));
            _selectedDeclaration = match;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }

    if (_selectedDeclaration != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Current selection ({0}) is '{1}' ({2})", selection, _selectedDeclaration.IdentifierName, _selectedDeclaration.DeclarationType);
    }

    return _selectedDeclaration;
}

private static bool IsSelectedDeclaration(QualifiedSelection selection, Declaration declaration)
{
    return declaration.QualifiedSelection.QualifiedName.Equals(selection.QualifiedName)
           && (declaration.QualifiedSelection.Selection.ContainsFirstCharacter(selection.Selection));
}

private static bool IsSelectedReference(QualifiedSelection selection, IdentifierReference reference)
{
    return reference.QualifiedModuleName.Equals(selection.QualifiedName)
           && reference.Selection.ContainsFirstCharacter(selection.Selection);
}
```

Comment: Any reason `Initialize()` is public?

Comment: @eurotrash yeah - the class is instantiated well before the VBE is ready for any interaction, so the `App` class calls it when it's ready. Fairly possible that I need more factories in my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a small nesting inside the first `if` statement you can skip the multiple checks for `declaration != null` which would make the code a little bit more readable like so

```
public void SetSelectionText(Declaration declaration)
{
    if (declaration == null)
    {
        if(_vbe.ActiveCodePane == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var selection = _vbe.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection();
        SetSelectionText(selection);
    }
    else if (!declaration.IsBuiltIn && declaration.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Class && declaration.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Module)
    {
        _selectionButton.Caption = string.Format("{0} ({1}): {2} ({3})",
            declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName,
            declaration.QualifiedSelection.Selection,
            declaration.IdentifierName,
            RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("DeclarationType_" + declaration.DeclarationType));
    }
    else
    {
        var selection = _vbe.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection();
        _selectionButton.Caption = string.Format("{0}: {1} ({2}) {3}",
            declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName,
            declaration.IdentifierName,
            RubberduckUI.ResourceManager.GetString("DeclarationType_" + declaration.DeclarationType),
            selection.Selection);
    }
}
```

you could extract the condition check of the `else if` to a method with a meaningful name. Although it would be only used once, it could improve the readability of the current method.

---

The `FindSelectedDeclaration()` method of the `RubberduckParserState` class could use some facelifting as well. If you swith the condition here `if (!selection.Equals(default(QualifiedSelection)))` you can return early and would save one level of indentation like so

```
public Declaration FindSelectedDeclaration(CodePane activeCodePane)
{
    var selection = activeCodePane.GetSelection();
    if (selection.Equals(_lastSelection))
    {
        return _selectedDeclaration;
    }

    _lastSelection = selection;
    _selectedDeclaration = null;

    if (selection.Equals(default(QualifiedSelection)))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var matches = AllDeclarations
        .Where(item => item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Project &&
                       item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.ModuleOption &&
                       item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Class &&
                       item.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Module &&
                       (IsSelectedDeclaration(selection, item) ||
                        item.References.Any(reference => IsSelectedReference(selection, reference))));
    try
    {
        var match = matches.SingleOrDefault() ?? AllUserDeclarations
            .SingleOrDefault(item => (item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Class || item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Module)
                    && item.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Equals(selection.QualifiedName));
        _selectedDeclaration = match;
    }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception);
        }

    if (_selectedDeclaration != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Current selection ({0}) is '{1}' ({2})", selection, _selectedDeclaration.IdentifierName, _selectedDeclaration.DeclarationType);
    }

    return _selectedDeclaration;
}
```

but if I read `var matches` or `var match` I always think about regular expressions, so I would prefer to rename these variables to `foundDeclarations` and `foundDeclaration`.